# help with bm25 explanation. Rare words in a small index/common words in a small index

Tags: algorithm, search, indexing, full-text-search, sphinx

I need a little help in understanding the bm25 relevance ranking (im using sphinx). When there is a small index (very small lets say), does this negatively influence relevance on common words that appear alot in a document? Lets say you have 4 articles total in the index (very small, yes)....titled: "norway", "canada stocks rebound again", "canada", "vietnam". The fields specified are title, and body. Lets say the query is : "canada". Basically, "canada" appears alot in (descending order)...i. "canada" ii. "canada stocks rebound again" iii. "norway" (it does in this article). Doesn't bm25 take into account word frequency? I read that words that appear very frequently in the index and the document actually take down the ranking. By the way, when I search in sphinx using proximity_bm25....."canada stocks rebound again" is ranked slightly higher than "canada"....curious :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some specific information on the Sphinx implementation of BM25 on [their blog](http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/08/17/how-sphinx-relevance-ranking-works/).  Note that that explanation begins *"BM25 ... depends on frequencies of the matched keywords only."*  The measure itself is primarily based on TF (Term Frequency) and IDF (Inverse Document Frequency); i.e. the frequency of the term across the entire corpus and the (inverse) number of documents containing that term.  The formulae is given in the referenced link.